# Get Assembly Version Info

Tags: c#

We have a large solution with about 30 projects.  We also have some common code utilities and as part of that utility class we have included a `GetAssemblyVersionInfo` method that returns the version info of that assembly.  However, we want to get the **Assembly Version Info** of the assembly for the project *not the utility DLL*.  Is there any way of having a utility function that returns the version info of another assembly based on execution and not passing around filenames?

EDIT:

For those who are curious, I solved it using:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

Comment: But if you call that line on your project it will return the `version` of the project assembly. Isn't it? Where is the problem so ?

Comment: Right, but I think the way I posted before fails because what happens if I had called the utility function from one layer deep?  It would return the assembly info of another utility DLL but what I want is the overall application that began the process.

Comment: Side note: Consider explicitly specifying assembly as argument to your `GetAssemblyVersionInfo` method - this will make code much cleaner, more readable and will allow you to test it in more senseble way.

Comment: The way were doing it right now is to specify the filename as an argument so basically build it: FileName + ".dll".  Should we just leave it this way?  I figured there was a cleaner way than passing around filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the assembly name, you can dynamically load it into the current AppDomain to retrieve the version info.

```
Assembly.LoadFrom(string.Format("{0}.dll", "assemblyshortname")).GetName().Version
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `GetEntryAssembly()` instead of `GetCallingAssembly()`.

Comment: Every time I call this I get a NullReferenceException.  Any ideas?

Comment: `GetEntryAssembly` returns null when the entry assembly is unmanaged. Note that the entry assembly of the mstest framework is unmanaged as well, so you when you run it in a test it is always null.